# Strange screen rotation behaviour in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, orientation

I have two Activities in my app.

The main activity is displayed when the device is in portrait position, and when the device is turned to landscape a 'summary screen' Activity (ShowAndTellActivity) is started.

This part of the app seems to work reliably and is achieved with the following:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orientation=newConfig.orientation;

    switch(orientation) {

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:

            show_and_tell_intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),ShowAndTellActivity.class);
            show_and_tell_intent.putExtra("each_pays", v_currency_symbol.concat(new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(v_each_to_pay)));
            startActivity(show_and_tell_intent);

            break;

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:

            break;

    }
}
```

The summary activity contains the following code to `finish()` the Activity when the device is rotated back to portrait position:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orientation=newConfig.orientation;

    switch(orientation) {

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:

            break;

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:

            finish();
            break;

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:

            finish();
            break;

    }
}
```

When the device is rotated back to portrait for the first time, however, the summary activity does not finish - instead the summary screen is displayed in portrait (which looks bad).

Rotating the device back to landscape (summary screen looks OK again) and back to portrait a second time results in the summary activity finishing as expected.

From this point on rotating the device seems to work reliably with the app switching between activities correctly. In other words it is only the first rotation back to portrait that does not seem to trigger the `finish()` of the summary activity.

It's almost as though when the summary screen Activity starts, it doesn't know its orientation until it has changed once.

Comment: You can lock activities to only display in a single orientation in the manifest.  I suggest you do that instead.

Comment: @Gabe Locking the orientation in the manifest would prevent the app from detecting the rotation and therefore prevent the summary activity from displaying. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Personally I would consider that a feature, I hate it when apps change to showing me something completely different on rotation.  But in that case, have you considered making the summary a fragment, and using the built in rotation display change behavior to display a layout with that fragment instead of the normal one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reliable way I could find to achieve this was to write my own rotation detection handler:

```
    myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int deviceAngle){
            if (deviceAngle >= 320 || deviceAngle <= 40) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
```

Using the built in onConfigurationChanged in the second activity just wasn't reliable - it always failed on the first rotation back from landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. In my case, `onConfigurationChanged` was not getting called the first time. For me `onRestoreInstanceState()` worked

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
        switch(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                break;

            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                finish();
                break;

            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                finish();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems I was a bit swift to accept this answer. It solves the problem I described in the Android Studio emulator but not on my HTC 10 so it seems not to quite be a proper fix.... So I'm still stuck with the bug.